# image key frame issue

Tags: animation, import, image, selection-tools

After I import an image, subdivide and extrude I use C to take circles of the image apart, then hit P to separate.  Then I rotate and move to a new location and use a keyframe to record the action.

The fist time I do this, everything works fine. The second time, the entire image moves to the second section that's moved.   Using B cause the same problem, but not on the first section, only after later sections.

I can add particle streams to each section (explode and move) without a problem, but I can't get the new parts to rotate and move.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure you are keyframing it right? Insert key frame on frame 1, go to frame X move piece and insert another keyframe.

Comment: Yes, the first keyframe works and the problem comes only after I add a second or third keyframe.

Comment: It sounds like the separated parts are still linked with the old data.  If you find these objects in your layout, check their geometry strips,(tiny triangle), see if there's one there that's for the object they were taken from.  If so, right click on it and select "Unlink".  Do the same of there are any for strips for "Animation".  If so right click on those and "Clear animation".

Comment: That didn't work for me, but the unlink comment led me to a Google Search for the shortcut U, which worked.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't find anything that works consistently....a lot of trial and error.  Lots of controls z to undo, then unlinking the original image etc....not something I want to do again.....too time-consuming.